# How to change sheet name to next month automatically

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Test
    Sheets(“August”).Name=“=Text(Eomonth(Today(),1),””mmmm””)”
End sub
```

I am trying to change sheet 2’s name to the next month when I run my macro at the end of the month. How do I accomplish this so that I don’t have to do it manually?

Comment: Please clarify, do you want to rename the same worksheet with the next months' name, every month? or Are you creating a new worksheets for the next month?

Comment: I am renaming the same sheet with the next month’s name at the end of every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [WorksheetFunction.EoMonth method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.eomonth) and [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("August").Name = Format$(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 1), "mmmm")
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBE double click on "ThisWorkbook" in your VBAProject pane (highlighted in the picture below).

[image]

Also make note of the Sheet number in the VBAProject window for the tab you want to name. It will be the `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3` name outside of the parentheses. You can then paste in this code that will execute every time the Workbook is opened.

Here I have this set as `Sheet1`, but change to whichever Sheet/Tab it is that you want to change.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheet1.Name = Format(Now(), "mmmm")
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I get it to do the next month? So it’s August and I want it to say September and so forth.

Comment: Also, how do I get this to work in a module instead of this workbook?

Comment: `Sheet1.Name = Format(DateAdd("m", 1, Now()), "mmmm")` will do the trick. Feel free to copy and paste that into whatever moduule, subroutine, or function you wish. Just update that `Sheet1` to be which ever Sheet's codename you are trying to change.